# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 isn't installing ( Error: Update 4 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, failed-installation

I've had Visual Studio 2013 installed for a while, but after experiencing certain issues, thought I would try reinstalling.

I completely removed VS2013, and tried to install the full application with update 4 included... i.e. from the complete 6GB install package.

Immediately after starting the installer, it immediately said:
Update 4 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The last few lines of the log file is:

```
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i101: Detected package: sqlsysclrtypes_Sql2014_amd64_rus, state: Obsolete, cached: None
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i101: Detected package: sharedmanagementobjects_Sql2014_x86_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i101: Detected package: sharedmanagementobjects_Sql2014_amd64_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i101: Detected package: SSDTJuneau_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i052: Condition '(CurrentOperation = "Install") OR (CurrentOperation = "Repair")' evaluates to true.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : Update 4 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[1E08:1E58][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[1E08:16F0][2015-01-11T11:02:04]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Comment: I have the same problem and i'm stuck with it. I'm using 2013 Ultimate with Update 3 Version 12.0.30723.00.

Will update if i find anything

Comment: Update:
I went to MS http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832426&clcid=0x409 site
and downloaded VS Ultimate 2013 with Update 4 ISO Image.
installed. When i open VS 2013 it had Update 4.
Good luck

Comment: seems like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883039/visual-studio-2013-update-4-isnt-installing-error-update-4-does-not-apply-o pls make a search on stack overflow before posting already answered questions.

Comment: @ingconti: it is the same question

Answer (score 1):

> This issue occurs when you run an update for Visual Studio and don't
>   have any of the core Visual Studio components installed.

e.g. The file VS2013.5.exe can represent Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

You may however, still need to install Visual Studio 2013 before running this update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to install Windows (your O.S.version) [SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)

package to solve it.